# What is the meaning of npm init -y

Tags: npm, init

What is the use of the flag `-y` in the `npm init` command? I noticed it is used in setting up an `npm` project, but what exactly does it mean?

```
npm init -y
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if they answered your question correctly.

Answer (score 34):

The `-y` flag when passed to NPM commands tells the generator to use the defaults instead of asking the usual questions.

```
npm init -y
```

will simply generate an empty npm project without going through an interactive process and fill the JSON with preset values.

The `-y` stands for `yes`.[More about npm-init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

Answer (score 6):

from `npm help init`:

```
   Generate it without having it ask any questions:

     $ npm init -y
```